# How to resolve issue with null object?

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Errors:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.ImageView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

or

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageView.setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)'
```

SecondLayout.xml:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cafe"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/cafe" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/baron"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:src="@drawable/bar" />
```

The first class has OneLayout.xml

ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class has SecondLayout.xml

In the first class, when you click on the marker, ExampleBottomSheetDialog.class is activated:

```
public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {

    ExampleBottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new ExampleBottomSheetDialog();
    bottomSheet.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "exampleBottomSheet");

    // Image replacement
    if (...) {
        ImageView img= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.cafe);
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.bar);
    }
```

How to resolve issue with null object?

Answer (score 2):

You try to access the `ImageView` of the `ExampleBottomSheetDialog` whereas the view is not created (so the `ImageView` is null). 
You must give arguments to your `ExampleBottomSheetDialog` and manage the ImageView resource drawable in the `ExampleBottomSheetDialog` class (in the `onCreateDialog` method for example).